# UIView move up & down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswipegesturerecognizer

currently I am moving uiviews from left to right on the swipe gesture of  down how can I change transition to up and down

```
-(void)slideToRightWithGestureRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self.calendar.frame = CGRectOffset(self.calendar.frame, 320.0, 0.0);
    self.secondCalender.frame = CGRectOffset(self.secondCalender.frame, 320.0, 0.0);
}];
}
```

Comment: just change the y-coordinates --> up and down , if you want to move left and right just change the x-coordinates, fine

Comment: Can you show the code that you init the gesture?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik problem solved and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last parameter in CGRectOffset is the vertical offset. Pass a non-zero value in that and you'll move the view up/down.

```
/* Offset `rect' by `(dx, dy)'. */

CGRect CGRectOffset(CGRect rect, CGFloat dx, CGFloat dy)
```

Comment: can you elaborate more

Comment: change `self.calendar.frame = CGRectOffset(self.calendar.frame, 320.0, 0.0);` to `self.calendar.frame = CGRectOffset(self.calendar.frame, 0.0, 320.0);`